# Como desabilitar demais botões em um foreach quando clicar em um único botão?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um grid com uma relação de limpezas a serem feitas. Inicialmente todos os botões estão verdes com o texto "Iniciar Limpeza". Quando inicio uma limpeza, esse botão passa a ter a cor azul e o texto muda para "Continuar Limpeza".

Perfeito, isso já está funcionando. Gostaria que, enquanto houvesse uma limpeza em aberto, que os demais botões ficassem desabilitados, e voltassem a ficar habilitados somente após a limpeza em aberto ser concluída.

A ideia é não permitir que o usuário inicie uma limpeza sem finalizar a que está em aberto. Abaixo o trecho do meu código que está dentro de um foreach:

```
<tr style="background-color:<?php echo $corFundoSujoAgendado?>;color: <?php echo $corQuartoSujoAgendado; ?>">
    <td><center><?php echo $quartos["quarto"];  ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo date("d/m/Y H:i",strtotime($quartos["solicitado_em"]));  ?></center></td>
    <td>
    <center>
        <?php if (count($limpezaEmAbertoPorIDLimpeza) > 0)  {?>
        <a  class='ui button fluid blue iniciarLimpeza' href="javascript:exibirLimpezaParaIniciar(<?php echo $idLimpezaQuartoSujoAgendado;  ?>);" ><span class="iniciar">Continuar limpeza</span>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp
                    </a>                                                                                            
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a  class='ui button fluid green iniciarLimpeza' href="javascript:exibirLimpezaParaIniciar(<?php echo $idLimpezaQuartoSujoAgendado;  ?>);" ><span class="iniciar">Iniciar Limpeza</span>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp
                    </a>
        <?php } ?>
    </center>                                                                            

    </td>
```

[image: Relação de LImpezas]

Comment: O trecho de código que você colocou de exemplo na pergunta está quebrado, corrija ele, por favor. Se possível também forneça o código HTML desses botões.

Comment: hehehe, não estou achando a opção para editar a pergunta.. sou novo no site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia a todos! Obrigado pela ajuda. Consegui uma solução mais simples que compartilho com vocês abaixo:

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {        
            if ($(".continuarLimpeza").length == 0) 
            {
                $(".iniciarLimpeza").removeClass("disabled")
            } 
            else 
            {
                    $(".iniciarLimpeza").addClass("disabled")
                    $(".continuarLimpeza").removeClass("disabled")
            }
            return; 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode escutar as mudanças com o change :
https://api.jquery.com/change/
Com isso use o jQuery pra mudar a propriedade

> $("input").prop('disabled', true)

Comment: vou tentar aqui Eduardo. Obrigado